# Using Jmeter OS Process Sampler to collect script data

Tags: python, command, jmeter

Is it possible to collect the output of a python script using the "OS Process Sampler"?

My python script does a database query and returns "r1=123 r2=456 r3=789"
Is there a way to collect the r1, r2, r3 values and graph them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) to get the values from the OS Process Sampler as follows:

1. Add Regular Expression Extractor as a child of the OS Process Sampler
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Reference Name: variable name of your choice, i.e. `r`
   - Regular Expression: `r1=(\d+) r2=(\d+) r3=(\d+)`
   - Template: `$1$$2$$3$`

It will result in the following variables:

```
r=123456789
r_g=3
r_g0=r1=123 r2=456 r3=789
r_g1=123
r_g2=456
r_g3=789
```

You can "tell" JMeter to store these values into .jtl results file by adding the following line to *user.properties* file (it is located in /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

```
sample_variables=r_g1,r_g2,r_g3
```

Variables will be stored in .jtl file along with the other test result information like

```
1434196234292,251,OS Process Sampler,0,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,21,1,1,0,123,456,789
```

(scroll to the right of the line as the values may be hidden)

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) to learn more about JMeter properties and ways of setting/overriding them.

Once you store results you should be able to graph the values you can use Microsoft Excel, [Libre Office](https://www.libreoffice.org/) or equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you just have to print the data you need to pass to jmeter, and then use one  (or more) regular expression to extract values.